# append anaconda packages path permanently for ipython notebook in Windows 7

Tags: windows, python-3.x, ipython, jupyter-notebook, pythonpath

how should I append anaconda packages path permanently for ipython notebook in Windows 7.I know that there is sys.path.append function but that does the work only till the session is alive so its temporary.

Comment: One option is to set the PYTHONPATH environment variable. But if you use Jupyter installed in Anaconda, it should know about those packages automatically.

Comment: Python and Ipython console are working well when it calls anaconda modules but when I work from jupyter notebook I need to append path like  sys.path.append("PATH_TO_ANOCONDA_Package").So how should I fix that for permanent

Comment: Oh, it sounds like your IPython kernel is set up somewhere else. Use `jupyter kernelspec list` to see where kernelspecs are installed. You may want to remove a kernelspec if it's set up from another environment, or [install a kernelspec](http://ipython.readthedocs.io/en/stable/install/kernel_install.html) from the environment you're currently working in.

Comment: I saw where kernel spec is installed but how to know its somewhere else? And how to remove the kernelspecs and what does removing kernel specs means.I'm not from Computer Science background so I'm sorry if I'm asking very easy question...

Comment: Kernel specs tell Jupyter how to launch a kernel (the process that runs your code). If you create one from a given environment or Python installation, your code in a notebook will run in that environment.

Comment: Thank you Thomas :)